# Excel 2010/2013 - Need to count number of doses of a medication given on the same date, to the same patient MR#

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Okay, a colleague is trying to compile some dosage information. He has a spreadsheet containing Dates of Service, the patient's Medical Record #, and the name of the Medication. So, if Oxycodone appears 3 times on 9/30/15 for Medical Record 012345678 then what he would like to automatically receive is a report that looks like:

Serv Date......      MedRec#..........        Rx.................         Doses

9/30/2015......      012345678......   Oxycodone......    3

9/29/2015......0123455567......   Aspirin............    1

9/29/2015......0000345678......   Rantidine......    2

Of course he has a huge number of dates, patients, and various meds for each patient on various days, so the above would cover many months for patients on various meds. I tried CountIF, and initially a Pivot Table looked promising but I'm lacking the skill and its driving me bats on how to automatically return a count for so many conditions being met and pulling the Rx name, Dates of Service, and Med Rec # out of the sheet and producing the report on a new sheet. 
   Any ideas?

Comment: so you have "number of doses" in your raw data table? Or does one row implicitly indicate 1 dose?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data looks like this :

[image]

Add a column on the left, which will be a composite index based on Date, medrec# and Rx (I use a semicolon as a seperator) : `=CONCATENATE(B2,";",C2,";",D2)`

[image]

Now all you need to do is use COUNTIF to count the frequency of that INDEX (which would equal the number of Doses) : `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)`

[image]

Then you can use Excel's Advance Filters to show only unique values :

[image]

Which will give you this filtered table :

[image]